# Update MySQL Query timesout

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

tablea
zone
latitude
longitude

tableb
zone
Lat
Long

I am trying to move the latitudes and longitudes from tableb into new columns in tablea. But when I run the below query even on just one column it times out after 5 or 6 minutes.

```
UPDATE tablea SET latitude=(SELECT Lat FROM tableb WHERE tableb.zone=tablea.zone)
```

How can I merge these tables?

Comment: Are your tables properly indexed?

Comment: Nope what would you suggest for the above structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE tablea JOIN table b 
ON tablea.zone=tableb.zone
SET tablea.latitude=tableb.lat
```

Also index your zone columns on both tables.

Comment: ALTER TABLE `tableb` ADD INDEX ( `zone` ) ; this timed out as well though

Comment: 1.2 mil in tablea and 200k in tableb

Comment: I reimported tableb with an index on zone and it ran after 2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do it like that :

```
UPDATE tablea , tableb
SET tablea.latitude = tableb.Lat
WHERE tablea.zone= tableb.zone;
```

Answer (score 0):

On `tableb`, create an index that covers both `zone` and `Lat`:

```
ALTER TABLE `tableb` ADD INDEX ( `zone`, `Lat` ) ;
```

That should drastically speed up the performance of your query.

Comment: This timed out as well